# Confusion 2D and 3D

Tags: circles, spheres

I don't understand why I obtain a cone in 3D if I plot the function of a circle : x^2+y^2 = 0.

Why I do not get a circle in 2D ?

For example, when I plot y = x, I have a line because it's in two dimensions, when I plot y = 1 or x = 1 it is in one dimension. So why for x^2 + y^2 = 0 it's in three dimensions ?

Same, a sphere equation (eg: (x-1)^2 + (y-1)^2 + (z-1)^2 = 0 ) is in 3D as well as the circle one, so that's my confusion

I hope I didnt say to many ineptitudes...

Comment: In 2D, $x^2+y^2=0$ is a point. In 3D, it is a line.

Comment: You don't obtain the equation of the cone if you do what you did. Let's also fix the equation of circle: say, $x^2+y^2=1$. Then, in a $x-y$ plane, this is an equation of a circle, but in the $x-y-z$ space this is an equation of a *cylinder* that is orthogonal to the $x-y$ plane and intersects it on that circle. This is because this equation prescribes what $x$ and $y$ must be, while $z$ (being not even mentioned in the equation) can be arbitrary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The equation itself does not determine how many dimensions you are working in. The number of dimensions has to be specified independently. For example, $x=1$ could be graphed in 1 dimension, where it's a point; or 2 dimensions, where it's a line; or 3 dimensions, where it's a plane, etc.  Same for your other examples.

Also, the equation $x^2+y^2=0$ in 2 dimensions is not a circle.  It is a point, because the only (real) numbers $(x,y)$ that satisfy $x^2+y^2=0$ are $x=0, y=0$. To get a circle, the right hand side needs to be a positive number, for example $x^2 + y^2 = 1$.  Same with the sphere.

Comment: Right so it's just a question of perception ? Given an equation I can't know how many parameters I have because they could be equal to 0 ? How do I specify how many dimensions do I have ?

Comment: You specify by just stating it.  For example, "This is the graph of $x=1$ in 3 dimensions".

Answer (score 1):

One of the ways in which you may get more insight, is by thinking about how many degrees of freedom you have for a given equation. For example if you consider the equation $x^{2} + y^{2} = 0$. You can see that the only points $(x,y,z)$ in the three dimensional space that satisfy this equation are all the points for which $x = 0$ and $y = 0$. These are all the points $(0,0,z)$ where $z$ is a real number. Thus in three dimensional space, this equation yields a line.

The reason why you do not get a circle in two dimension is because the general equation for a circle in two dimensions is $x^{2} + y^{2} = r^{2}$, where $r$ is the radius of the circle. The equation you have written is a circle with radius $0$ and hence it is just a point in two dimensions.

If you choose a radius different from $r$ this equation will yield a circle in two dimensions and a cylinder in three dimension. Again, the easiest way to tackle such problems is by closely examining which points in the space satisfy the equations.

Comment: ok thanks a lot :) last question if I have an equality for example x+y-1=0, how do I know which side is positive or negative with some calculus ?